# How to include a php library in your project ? [developing a website]

Tags: php, braintree

I am trying to include braintree (provides api for accepting payments online) php library in my project. is there a way where i can just copy the library into the server. As i am not familiar with the whole composer thing!

Comment: I downvoted this question, because [the official documentation](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php) starts with "**Download this zipfile** *or* use composer". So I think that first line alone answers your question, and the rest of the page shows the details. I think the question shows little research effort, which is especially worrying when you are implementing online payments. It's people's money you are messing with.

Comment: you clearly didnt read my question. I understand the documentation my problem is including a php library to a server or how to use a composer. dont just say your pinion without even reading what is the problem.

Comment: Although i didn't downvote, i think GolezTrol is right. If its a composer question just search how to use composer and also rephrase your question

Answer (score 3):

GolezTrol answered this already, as the first thing the documentation says is how to use it without composer, but if you download: `https://developers.braintreepayments.com/client_libraries/php/braintree-php-3.7.0.tgz`

Upload that to your server and write the following to your website:

```
require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree\Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree\Configuration::merchantId('your_merchant_id');
Braintree\Configuration::publicKey('your_public_key');
Braintree\Configuration::privateKey('your_private_key');
```

Then you can follow the API to complete the process.
I hope that after 11 months you had already solved this.

Comment: Hi Tom, If I only unzip and upload to my server it will work? because I have tried and it seems like my android app is not receiving a token  'A client token or tokenization key must be specified in the DropInRequest'

Comment: I was looking over old comments, thought i'd look this up: https://github.com/braintree/braintree-android-drop-in#usage

Though I would hope that you had a solution by now.

Comment: yes i have found solution and even wrote a blogpost here : http://mangoprojects.info/android-2/using-braintree-sdk-on-android-for-paypal-and-credit-card-payments/

Answer (score 1):

This link will get you up and running with composer https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Just create a **`composer.json`** file and add the following

```
{
  "require" : {
    "braintree/braintree_php" : "2.35.2"
  }
}
```

And then run:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Or you could just download https://www.braintreepayments.com/assets/client_libraries/php/braintree-php-2.35.2.tgz

Comment: how do i run it or where should i put this line in the code. and if i downloaded the library where should i put in my server?

Comment: just add require 'vendor/autoload.php'; in your file if you are using compser

Comment: how exactly should i add it in the top of the php file

Comment: ys... or in your common index.php which runs all files or header.php which is included in all files